# Увеличение блока при клике и переход

Tags: javascript, css, frontend

подскажите как сделать такой эффект при переходе на страницу. [image: сам блок]

В данном блоке на фоне проигрывается видео и при клике необходимо, чтобы блок увеличивался по контуру самолета до фулл размера и осуществлялся переход на страницу. Через clip, отрисовывать каждую точку не подходит.

Подскажите, как так возможно сделать, есть ли какие то примеры

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Я бы решал данную задачу через масштабирование свойства [clip-path](https://codepen.io/DeeDee23/pen/vKVwzd)
для видео...

```
const vid = document.getElementsByTagName('VIDEO')[0];
const button = document.getElementsByTagName('BUTTON')[0];
button.addEventListener('click', () => vid.play());
```

Повесил бы обработчик клика на оббертку блока, и по нажатию его масштабировал что бы видео становилось видимым